# aaply fails on a vector

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to understand how to use the excellent plyr package's commands on a vector (in my case, of strings). I suppose I'd want to use aaply, but it fails, asking for a margin. But there aren't columns or rows in my vector!

To be a bit more concrete, the following command works, but returns results in a wierd list. states.df is a data frame, and region is the name of the state (returned using Hadley's map_data("state") command). Thus, states.df$region is a vector of strings (specifically, state names). opinion.new is a vector of numbers, named using state names.

```
states.df <- map_data("state")
ch = sapply(states.df$region, function (x) { opinion.new[names(opinion.new)==x] } )
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
ch = aaply(states.df$region, function (x) { opinion.new[names(opinion.new)==x] } )
```

Where ch is the vector of numbers looked up or pulled from opinion.new. But aaply requires an array, and fails on a vector.

Thanks!

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but the general use case for plyr is the split-apply-combine (SAC) process. You can't really SAC a vector. While I use (abuse) plyr all the time, this seems like a better fit for `sapply()`. Were you wanting to use plyr as a learning exercise?

Comment: Yes, I'm always trying to grok it. sapply does work, but returns a really ugly list that can't be coerced back into a vector. But I understand if plyr doesn't operate on vectors.

Comment: Of course, the easiest way to do the table lookup here is simply opinion.new[states.df$region]. But I was trying to learn how to use plyr on vectors, which I guess I can't.

Comment: I loaded up the data and then created an opinion.new vector and was looking at what you were doing. I think your conclusion is accurate. This problem is solved by `[` and not really something plyr is geared up to do.

Comment: Thanks JD. I was just hoping for a generic, go-through-each-element-of-the-vector command (this probably just wasn't a good example with such an easy solution), and I guess sapply is it. Unfortunate that it returns lists.

Comment: A vector has one margin: 1. If you supply that it should work. You can also use l*ply with vectors.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use plyr on a vector, you have to use l*ply, as follows:

```
v <- 1:10
sapply(v, function(x)x^2)
 [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100

laply(v, function(x)x^2)
 [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

In other words, sapply and laply are equivalent

Comment: You can still use `aaply` too: `aaply(v, 1,function(x) x^2)`